# Nesting multiple for using in

Tags: javascript

When I place the code below I would like to access a deeper level of the object nesting two `for` using `in`. I am new to this so I guess I am missing something.

I have tried nesting both `for` statements without success.

```
let user = {
    name: 'Kenneth',
    age: 28,
    data: {
      username: 'kennethCodesAllDay',
      joinDate: 'March 26, 2016',
      organization: 'freeCodeCamp',
      friends: [
        'Sam',
        'Kira',
        'Tomo'
      ],
      location: {
        city: 'San Francisco',
        state: 'CA',
        country: 'USA'
      }
    }
  };

for (keys in user) {
    console.log(keys) //properly returns: age, name, data
    for (deeper in user[keys]) {  
        console.log(deeper)// wrongly returns: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, username, joinDate, organization, friends, location.
}
```

I would like to get the following:

```
console.log(deeper) => username, joinDate, organization, friends, location.
```

Comment: Sounds like you might just want `Object.keys(user.data)`?

Comment: You only need to run your inner `for...in` loop if `user[keys]` is an object (or if `keys==="data"`), you don't want to iterate over your string values.

Comment: for (keys in user.data) { console.log(keys) }

Comment: I think what he need is if (user[keys] instanceof Object)
or similar.

Answer (score 2):

The string value of "name" will be treated as a String instance, and each character is indexed numerically in that object. That's where the numbers are coming from, as you can see if you check what

```
for (let x in "Kenneth") console.log(x);
```

prints.

If before the inner loop you check to make sure that the property value is an object, things will work more like what you expect (for this object anyway).

Make sure you declare `keys` and `deeper`.

```
for (let keys in user) {
    console.log(keys) //properly returns: age, name, data
    if (user[keys] instanceof Object)
        for (let deeper in user[keys])   
            console.log(deeper);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I've got some questions back: 1. Why the loop is ignoring the content of ```key``` 'age' which is a number (28)? Could you please give me an example of how could I determine that ```deeper``` will only look into object property values?

Comment: I have now actually tested ```console.log(Object.keys(user[keys]))``` at the first ```for...in``` iteration and got a return of: ```[ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' ],[] ​​​​​,[ 'username', 'joinDate', 'organization', 'friends', 'location' ] ``` Now I understand that ```age: 28``` is actually looped in ```deeper```, but considered as empty ```[]```. Why is that? Once again, thanks very much. This will help me to understand more about objects & arrays.

Comment: @Alioshr it helps to add some extra information to your `console.log()` calls so you can tell which one is which, like `console.log("user key: " + keys)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for the comments!

I have done the following:

```
for (let keys in user) {
      console.log(keys)
      if (user[keys] instanceof Object) {
      for (let deeper in user[keys]) {   
    console.log(deeper)
      }
    }
  }
```

In this attempt `console.log(deeper)` returns: `username, joinDate, organization, friends, location.`

As far as I have reasoned, it seems to work as it should. Could anyone please comment?